# android logcat showing empty logs -- how to enable logging?

Tags: android, logcat, android-4.2-jelly-bean

I just got an Alcatel onetouch phone for development. It's running Android 4.1.2 (JellyBean API level 16). When I use `adb logcat` it shows the empty output below

> ```
> >"C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe" logcat
> --------- beginning of /dev/log/system
> --------- beginning of /dev/log/main
> ```

I've used logcat before on other devices and it shows all sorts of activities and logging just as you do normal navigation on the phone.

This makes me think that the phone has logging disabled. Under the "About phone" page in the Settings app there is an "Advanced settings" section, which contains lots of stuff about debugging, including the option to turn on USB debugging, but also lots of things like "Show screen updates" that I haven't seen in other android versions/devices. It has a section called "Monitoring" and under that there is something called "Enable traces". But I enabled all 8 of them, and I don't think they are related to logcat logging. I was hoping to see a setting that would allow me to enable logcat logging but can't find it (i.e., enable the type of logging that logcat traditionally shows).

Any ideas?

Comment: Try `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe" shell logcat`. I guess adb itself uses that command, but it might be worth a try.

Comment: @user1561072 I could spend the rest of the morning going into detail of what is wrong with your comment.

Comment: @Simon I'm sorry, just tried to help.

Comment: @justlerning  You are right.  I was wrong.  I've +1ed one of your answers to make amends.  My apologies to you.

Comment: @Simon No problem. Thank you for admitting it. Good to have honest people around.